# Deleting decimals and non digits from string column using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe column with strings like this:

```
df.column1:
0 R$ 27.467.522,00 (Vinte e sete milhões, quatro...
1 NaN
2 R$ 35.314.312,12 (Trinta e cinco milhões, trezentos...
3 R$ 1.231,34 (Mil duzentos e trinta e um reais e...
```

I want only to get the numbers, disconsidering the decimals, so it gets to look like this:

```
df.column1:
0 27467522
1 NaN
2 35314312
3 1231
```

I'm trying to do that with regex:

```
df['column1']=df['column1'].str.extract('[REGEX CODE]')
```

However I'm not used with Regex. I tried solutions like:

```
df['column1']=df['column1'].str.extract('(.*?,)').str.extract('(\d+)')
df['column1']=df['column1'].str.extract('(\s*,.*)').str.extract('(\d+)')
```

But I haven't been able to make it right.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`str.replace`** then  **`str.extract`**

```
df.column1.str.replace('.', '').str.extract(r'(\d+)')

          0
0  27467522
1       NaN
2  35314312
3      1231
```

Decimals are indicated by commas here, so by replacing periods and using extract to find the first match, the number will be matched, ignoring the decimal.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but that doesn't pal. We will keep the decimals this way

Comment: Can you explain? It seems to me this matches your desired output.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, my confusion here. I didn't get how you made that work but it is working perfectly

Comment: if you want to keep the decimals, change the regex to `r'(\d+(,\d+)?)`. This way, it can cover both integers and decimals.
Afterwards, you may replace the ',' with '.'